# Post request in spray. How to capture it at server side?

Tags: json, scala, scala-2.10, spray, spray-json

I need to make a post request with Spray but i don't understand how to capture the request at server side. This is my code:

CLIENT:

```
.
.
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive

val fileName = "document.docx"
val path = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/test-documents/" + fileName)
val bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(path)
val bytes64 = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes)
val streamInString = new String(bytes64)
val json: JsonInputStream = JsonInputStream(fileName, streamInString)
val jsonString = write(json)

val response: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Post("http://localhost:8080/jsontest/", jsonString))
```

SERVER (the request is not captured in any of the 4 tests):

```
startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
    path("jsontest") {
      post {
        complete {
          <h1>TEST 1</h1>
        }
      }
    } ~
    path("jsontest" / Segment) { json =>
      post {
        complete {
          <h1>TEST 2</h1>
        }
      }
    } ~
    path("jsontest") {
      get {
        complete {
          <h1>TEST 3</h1>
        }
      }
    } ~
    path("jsontest" / Segment) { json =>
      get {
        complete {
          <h1>TEST 4</h1>
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

help me, please

Answer (score 0):

-.- simply delete "/" in `"http://localhost:8080/jsontest/"` and

```
path("jsontest") {
  post {
    complete {
      <h1>TEST 1</h1>
    }
  }
}
```

Capture it.
Sorry for my stupidity

Answer (score 0):

use the `entity` directive

have a look at http://spray.io/documentation/1.2-RC2/spray-routing/marshalling-directives/entity/#entity

it would be a great idea to use `application/json` for the content type